# How to test curried function in Karma/Jasmine

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine

I have a curried function such as

```js
  openDialog(info: string): (username: string) => Promise<string> {
    return (username: string) => {
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogModalComponent);
      return firstValueFrom<string>(dialogRef.afterClosed());
    };
  }
```

How may I test that openDialog was called with `info`, and the resulting function was called with `username`? The following won´t work.

```js
expect(component.openDialog).toHaveBeenCalledWith(info)(username);
```

I know currying is basically always a bad idea in TypeScript, but this kept me intrigued.